# R11 rated porcelain tiles for outdoor use

Tags: outdoor, pavers, porcelain, garden

I across the idea of "Anti-Slip Tile Ratings and Grades". Has anyone had R11 rated Porcelain tiles installed outdoors? I am interested to know if they are safe to use in the UK where it rains all the time and frost can happen in the winter.

Comment: Nothing works on ice, all bets are off. R11s should be about OK, 12s would be better [13s all look like the floor in a bus depot]